# Using a class as a type to declare a variable in another class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

In C++, how can I use a class that takes an argument to feed its constructor, as a new type, to declare a variable in another class (and use the input taken by the second class's constructor to feed the first class's constructor?)

What I want to do is something like the following but I don't know how to do the Object class part correctly and I keep getting errors (I don't want to derive the Object class from the Color class)

```
enum color_enum {red, blue, green, black};
class color
{
protected:
   color_enum col;
public:
   color(color_enum initval)
   {
      col = initval;
   }
   string str()
   {
      switch (col)
      {
      case red:
         return "red";
      case blue:
         return "blue";
      case green:
         return "green";
      case black:
         return "black";
      default:
         return "N/A";
   }
  }
};

ostream &operator<< (ostream &out, color &inst)
{
  out << inst.str();
  return out;
}

class Object
{
public:
  float objvolume;
  float objmass;
  string objname;
  color objcolor(initval);
};
```

Comment: a class [...] "to declare a variable in another class"? I'm sorry, I don't understand, could you please reformulate or give an example?

Comment: You either initialize with a hard-coded value (say `red`) or pass the value to the constructor of `Object`; in either case you should use the initializer list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an initializer list:

```
class Object {
public:
    Object(color_enum initval) : objcolor(initval){}
                          //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
                          //initialize objcolor with initval               
    //...
    color objcolor;
};

...

Object o(red); //objcolor will be constructed with red as an argument
```

In C++11, you can make use of in-class initialization and do:

```
color objcolor{red};
```

This only works for default values, though, not ones that are passed into a constructor.

Comment: So there isn't any way I can do that?

Comment: @MohammadSanei, You can't initialize it to a value passed in when the object is created without an initializer list.

Comment: I did what you suggested but I get an error saying: In constructor 'Object::Object(color_enum)' no matching function for call to 'color::color()'

Comment: @MohammadSanei, As long as each constructor has an initializer list that initializes it with a colour, or it has a default value, that shouldn't happen. Do make sure you keep the same order in the list as in the class if you're initializing more than just the colour.

Comment: It also says color isn't a direct base of Object. But that's my problem, I don't want to make my class a child of the class color. I did exactly what you told me to do! What is the problem?

Comment: @MohammadSanei, Could you post the code that's giving you issues?

Comment: int main()
{
  Object MyObject(black);
  return 0;
}

Comment: @MohammadSanei, [This code](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1T6lsE%246) compiles cleanly. Try comparing.

Comment: And I changed my Object class to what you suggested in your answer.

Comment: Thanks a thousand times! The problem was that I had written `: color(initval)` instead of `: objcolor(initval)`. Thank you! By the way, do you have any idea why I got two minus points for asking this question?

Comment: @MohammadSanei, It was probably from not being able to understand the question. It came through to me personally.